# SOQL count Persons having total linked objects >1

Tags: soql, community

I'm trying to count number of Persons having more than 1 optin with SOQL. The query i naturally wrote is this one, note that `Optin` is Account's child :

```
SELECT count(AccountId) 
FROM Account 
WHERE AccountId IN ( SELECT AccountId 
                     FROM Optin 
                     GROUP BY AccountId 
                     HAVING COUNT Count(OptinId) > 1
                   )
```

I'm having this error when I try to execute it :

```
MALFORMED_QUERY: 
Consumer__c FROM Email_Optin__c GROUP BY Consumer__c HAVING COUNT
ERROR at Row:1:Column:80
expecting a right parentheses, found 'GROUP'
```

In advance, thank you for your help !

Comment: do you have any relation between `account` and `Option`?

Comment: Yes Optin is an Account child: i just updated my question :)

Comment: you can perform an aggregate query against each child object individually like `SELECT count(id), AccountId FROM Optin GROUP BY AccountId`

Comment: Your solution does count number of Optins per Account, what i want to do is a total of Account with more than 1 Optin

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce doesn't support Group BY or HAVING in the inner query.

So, you need to create 2 separate queries as follows:

```
List<Id> acctIds =  [SELECT AccountId 
                     FROM Optin 
                     GROUP BY AccountId 
                     HAVING COUNT (Id) > 1];

List<AggregateResult> results = [SELECT count(Id) 
                                FROM Account 
                                WHERE AccountId IN :acctIds];
```

or, no need to perform 2nd query to get results.

Simply use `acctIds.size()` to get the count of Account

Comment: Thank you ! So there is no way to do this in a query editor ?